# utf-8 convert to utf-16

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, utf-16

i want to convert the chinese character to the unicode format, like '\uXXXX'
but when i use str.encode('utf-16be'), it'll show that:

```
b'\xOO\xOO'
```

so, i write some code to perform my request as below:

```
data="index=索引?"
print(data.encode('UTF-16LE'))

def convert(s):
    returnCode=[]
    temp=''
    for n in s.encode('utf-16be'):
        if temp=='':
            if str.replace(hex(n),'0x','')=='0':
                temp='00'
                continue
            temp+=str.replace(hex(n),'0x','')
        else:
            returnCode.append(temp+str.replace(hex(n),'0x',''))
            temp=''

    return returnCode

print(convert(data))
```

can someone give me suggestions to do this conversion in python 3.x?

Comment: what is the encoding of the file you define the string in?

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. UTF-16LE isn't Unicode, but it's what Microsoft calls "Unicode". Describe your goal, not your process.

Comment: `"index=索引?".encode('utf-16be')` gives `b'\x00i\x00n\x00d\x00e\x00x\x00=}"_\x15\x00?'` . What output did you want instead?

Comment: i want to convert the characters to the format '\uXXXX'. like this:
`index=\u0069\u006e\u0064\u0065\u0078\u003d\u7d22\u5f15\u003f`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand you well.

Unicode is like a type. In python 3, all strings are unicode, so when you write `data = "index=索引?"` then data is already unicode. If you want to get an alternative representation just for displaying, you could use:

```
def display_unicode(data):
    return "".join(["\\u%s" % hex(ord(l))[2:].zfill(4) for l in data])

>>> data = "index=索引?"
>>> print(display_unicode(data))
\u0069\u006e\u0064\u0065\u0078\u003d\u7d22\u5f15\u003f
```

Note that the string has now real backslashes and numeric representations, not unicode characters.

But there may be other alternatives

```
>>> data.encode('ascii', 'backslashreplace')
b'index=\\u7d22\\u5f15?'
>>> data.encode('unicode_escape')
b'index=\\u7d22\\u5f15?'
```

Comment: OP is almost certainly using Python 3 - see print being used as a function, and a `b''` literal. Also, encoding of text files doesn't necessarily follow `$LANG` - IDEs and text editors often let you set it in their configuration, and have their own defaults.

Comment: i use python3.3, the default coding is UTF-8

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the question correctly. Doesn't `data.encode('ascii', 'backslashreplace')` do the trick?

Answer (score 1):

Try to decode first, like: `s.decode('utf-8').encode('utf-16be')`?

Comment: The parens on `print` imply Python 3.x.